# Angular 6 Property 'invalid' does not exist on type 'string'

Tags: angular6

I am down to two errors (same error in two locations in the html)

```
    <label for="category"
      >Category
      <select
        class="form-control category"
        [(ngModel)]="productModel.category"
        #title="ngModel"
        [ngClass]="{ 'is-invalid': pf.submitted && category.invalid }"
        name="category"
        placeholder="Please select a Category"
        required
        category
      >
        <option value="">Please select a Category</option>
        <option
          *ngFor="let item of (this.categoryObj | keyvalue); let i = index"
          value="{{ item.key }}"
          >{{ item.key }}</option
        >
      </select></label
    >
    <div *ngIf="pf.submitted && category.invalid" class="invalid-feedback">
      <div *ngIf="category.errors.required">Category is required</div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

I have tried to declare invalid to the component as the following:

```
invalid = "";
```

and

```
invalid: boolean;
```

But no matter what, I still receive:

```
Property 'invalid' does not exist on type 'string'.
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is not pointing you towards a missing variable. It is telling you that a variable of type string does not have a value for property `invalid`. From the code snippet, the mismatch seems to happening here `category.invalid`

Comment: Thank you for replying @delwyn-pinto, I use this same logic with all the other fields. The only difference that I know of, is that this is a select and the others are inputs. Why would it have an issue with the select "category" and how do I fix it?

Comment: Select requires the property to be defined apparently. Why don't try defining category as an object with all its field having a blank value and see if that resolves it.

Comment: I was able to get around the error by not making it required. I have category declared as a type any, like I have all the other fields and they are all declared as properties of the model. Yet none of the other fields have this error. As a result, I just removed the required and the ngclass - and just like that, the error went away